# C# Generate barcode from datagridview to picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

**Is it possible to generate a barcode from a column selected in DataGridView?**

I want to show the ISBN as a barcode in the PictureBox
[image]

Here is my code

```
private void GunaDataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_13 };
  string txtBarcode = gunaDataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  picBarcode = writer.Write(txtBarcode);

  lblBarcode.Text = gunaDataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblBookTitle.Text = gunaDataGridView1[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblISBN.Text = gunaDataGridView1[4, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblCategory.Text = gunaDataGridView1[5, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblGenre.Text = gunaDataGridView1[6, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblMediaType.Text = gunaDataGridView1[7, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblLanguage.Text = gunaDataGridView1[8, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblAuthor.Text = gunaDataGridView1[9, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblPublisher.Text = gunaDataGridView1[10, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  lblPrice.Text = gunaDataGridView1[11, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

I am using **ZXing.Net** extension to generate a barcode.

I have tried

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_13 };
string txtBarcode = gunaDataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
picBarcode = writer.Write(txtBarcode);
```

But it is giving me an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

I have also tried the code

```
picBarcode = writer.Write(gunaDataGridView1[4, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

But it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set your `PictureBox` directly, you need to set its `Image` Property

```
picBarcode.Image = <your image>
```

Likely

```
picBarcode.Image = writer.Write(gunaDataGridView1[4, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Also remember to `Dispose` if you are setting it more than once (to clean up the *GDI resources*), you can achieve that *short-hand* using the [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators) operator and the `Dispose()` method

```
picBarcode.Image?.Dispose();
picBarcode.Image = <Your Image>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know it was that easy.